# Destroy Angular service after destroy component

Tags: angular, signalr, singleton

I have a problem with Angular SignalR service. My constructor in service call only once.
Flow:

1. Open browser and localHost for my app
2. Login to User
3. My header component call Service constructor normally and I have normal SignalR connection.
4. I log out(without refresh browser - app still work on main login page)
5. Header was destroyed and was called onDestroyed automatically(checked with console.log())
6. I logIn to User again(without refresh page)
7. constructor of SignalR Service didn't call again and I didn't have connection SignalR. Need to refresh page.

my Code below

```html
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalrService {
  private message$: Subject<string>;
  private messageGroup$: Subject<string>;
  private connection: signalR.HubConnection;
  connectionId: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log("constructor")
    this.message$ = new Subject<string>();
    this.messageGroup$ = new Subject<string>();
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${environment.apiUrl}/` + 'notify', {
        accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
      })
      .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 5000, 10000])
      .build();

    this.disconnect();
    this.connect();
  }

  public connect(): void {
    this.connection.start()
      .then(() => this.addUserToGroup())
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  public addBroadcastToUser(): void {
    this.connection.on('BroadcastToUser', (message) => {
      this.message$.next(message);
    });
  }

  public addFeedsUser(): void {
    this.connection.on('AddFeedsUser', (message) => {
      this.messageGroup$.next(message);
    });
  }

  public getMessage(): Observable<string> {
    return this.message$.asObservable();
  }

  public getGroupTradeRoomMessage(): Observable<string> {
    return this.messageGroup$.asObservable();
  }

  public disconnect(): void {
    this.connection.stop();
  }

  public getConnectionId = () => {
    this.connection.invoke('getConnectionId').then(
      (data) => {
        this.connectionId = data;
      }
    );
  };

  public addUserToGroup = () => {
    this.connection.invoke('addUserToGroup').then(
      (data) => {
        this.connectionId = data;
      }
    );
  };
}
```

I call from my Header Components

```html
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private signalRSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private signalrService: SignalrService) {

    this.signalrService.addBroadcastToUser();
    this.signalrService.addFeedsUser();

    this.signalRSubscription = this.signalrService.getMessage().subscribe(
      (message) => {
        this.onDataUpdate(message);
      });
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("destroy header")
    this.signalrService.disconnect();
    this.signalRSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I need build new Service when user logIn. I tried different ways. Init new Service in constructor of header app. It did't give normal result.
How I can fix it with normal Angular solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular have you covered on this one!
Instead of providing your service in root, add the **SignalrService** to your component's providers array. Then you will get a new **SignalrService** instance every time the component is created.

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [SignalrService]
})
HeaderComponent {}
```

Don't forget to remove the `providedIn: 'root'` from the **SignalrService**

```
@Injectable()
export class SignalrService {...}
```

Comment: now it call constructor normally but now I have new problem. SignalR service does`t work. Dont know why...

Comment: Please post more details... are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I dont have any errors in console. My signalR not working. Didn`t have any messages from backend. When I return message service "root" and remove from providers it is working as before.

Comment: Try a ReplySubject instead of a Subject for your message$ and messageGroup$. It's difficult to help without more details...

Comment: No it works good. I used this service in two components. When I removed this service for one of them. It works good. Thanks four solution. Now I will do own signalR service for each component. I didn`t use ReplySubject. Only removed from the second component this service.\

Answer (score 0):

Move the code in your services constructor to ngOnInit hook.

Comment: Unless of course you need a new service instance for each component. Then refer to @guzmanoj s answer.